# How to reduce the query quota in App engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, quota

The user will browse (paging) sorted entities in Datastore 12 at time.

```
 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

//get url parameter
int next = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("next") );
//query with sort
Query query = new Query("page").addSort("importance", SortDirection.DESCENDING );
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);

//get 12 entity from query result from the index (next)
FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(12).chunkSize(12).offset(next);

for (Entity result : pq.asIterable(options)) {
    Text text = (Text)result.getProperty("content");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text.getValue());

    //display the content
    .....
}
```

The problem is that when the next variable increase the quota consume increase faster!.

For example when the next is 6000, the quota consumed by 40%, while when the next is 10 the quota consumed by less than 1%.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit in what you are trying to do? Is this a simple paging? why is "next" variable if you can ony display 12 items at a time?

Comment: Yes, it is simple paging, and the next variable is the index of the first entity of the result of 12 item.

Comment: so your problem is that paginating through this list of entities consumes 40% of your read quota?

Comment: when you use count/offset then it reads every entity up through the offset, and you pay for it.  Instead you should be using cursors:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors

Comment: Yes this is what should I have did, That is because I have not fully read the documentations, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you use the Google App Engine cursors to facilitate your paging then your queries will be optimized. It is not recommended to use large offsets. The recommended way to do paging in GAE is with [cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors).